# TextBlock doesnt use all the space in button xaml C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, textblock, stackpanel

My textblock doesnt use the whole space inside the button, I need to decrease fontsize to be able to see it but I dont want to do that. It's getting too small. Isn't there a way to use this space in the button?

```
 <Button BorderThickness="0" 
         x:Name="btnBalance" 
         Click="btnBalance_Click"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="0,0,0,-5">

         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center">

                     <TextBlock Text="&#xE80C;" 
                                   FontSize="40" 
                                   FontFamily="/Fonts/fontello.ttf#fontello"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.CARD_OPERATIONS, 
                                   Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                                   FontSize="17"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="/Fonts/opensansregular.ttf#Open Sans"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Buttons are positioned equally within grid:

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: The text is rendered with a font and the size depends on the font family, size, and other settings. You can't stretch the text to fit the textblock.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? For me it uses all the space

Comment: I uploaded the image. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Do you have a "general" style that is implemented to all text blocks automatically? Or to the button or stack panels? I want to know if somewhere you are restricting the width of a control. Could be on a grid column as well.

Comment: You should mention in your post that it is `WindowsPhone`, I assumed `WPF`. Maybe there the rendering is different.

Comment: Could there be an inherited padding applied? Try setting the padding to 0 on the elements and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Slightly Off Topic: I think you misspelled "Passenger"

Comment: @NahuelIanni I don't have a general style applied to buttons, stack panels or textlocks.

Comment: @HockeyJ Setting padding to 0 didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textblock is inside the stackpanel, so if you want it more readable, just change the stackpanel's properties. This might do it:

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" 
     x:Name="btnBalance" 
     Click="btnBalance_Click"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Margin="0,0,0,-5">

     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"

    Height="150" Margin="-10,-10,0,0" Width="150" <!--These part-->
    >

                 <TextBlock Text="&#xE80C;" 
                               FontSize="40" 
                               FontFamily="/Fonts/fontello.ttf#fontello"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.CARD_OPERATIONS, 
                               Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                               FontSize="17"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               FontFamily="/Fonts/opensansregular.ttf#Open Sans"
                               Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

If it doesn't do what you want, change the `Height="150" Margin="-10,-10,0,0" Width="150"` part to resize and reposition the stackpanel.

Comment: well, at least you were right i guesss ... (isn't that : you're welcome, what ... jeez ...can't believe i typed thank you. too late ... no more computer for today...)